# Showing characters while typing in android?

Tags: android

I need to see characters while I am typing characters in keyboard.But i want to get result from keyboard.

This is not used below this code :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent KEvent) 
{
    int keyaction = KEvent.getAction();

    if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        int keycode = KEvent.getKeyCode();
        int keyunicode = KEvent.getUnicodeChar(KEvent.getMetaState() );
        char character = (char) keyunicode;

        System.out.println("DEBUG MESSAGE KEY=" + character + " KEYCODE=" +  keycode);
    }


    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(KEvent);
}
```

Comment: what do you want actually to achieve?

Comment: I want to press "A" Key that time i want to get output A.

Comment: Above this code only got number.can not get character value.

Comment: Hi psklink i am used KEYEVENT.KEYCODE_A.But not used

Comment: try `Character.toString` or something similar

Comment: Hi pskink it's not working stil same problem..

Comment: so use `KeyCharacterMap` to get the data

Comment: Hi pskink i am used // first option
int unicode = event.getUnicodeChar();

// second option with meta-state
int unicode = event.getUnicodeChar(event.getMetaState());

// third option over the KeyCharacterMap
KeyCharacterMap map = event.getKeyCharacterMap();
int unicode = map.get(keyCode, event.getMetaState());

Comment: But in those option not working pskink.How to get unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the text while typing into an android.widget.EditText you have to use the **android.text.TextWatcher**. Please try following:

1. Create an android.text.TextWatcher instance
2. Use the android.text.TextWatcher.onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) method to get the text
3. Add the android.text.TextWatcher you created to the android.widget.EditText by android.widget.EditText.addTextchangedListener(..your text watcher);

Your initially question was to get the pressed key. Therefore use the passed java.lang.CharSequence and get the last char by:

```
char lastKey = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
```

This should work. Before using this check if not null or if the length is actually not 0. So some checks before are always a good idea :-)

Hope this time you get your result!!
Good Programming!

P.S. I tried this right now in a dummy app with following code and it does work :-)

```
    this.editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    this.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {
            if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
                final char lastKey = s.charAt(s.length()-1);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(lastKey),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count,
                final int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro Thank you for your help.But this is not my requirement Ale.Ok i will ask one

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode,  android.view.KeyEvent event) {

  switch(keyCode){

   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
    Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
    Toast.makeText(this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
    Toast.makeText(this, "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
 
  }
  return onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

Comment: Number's is working well but character it's not working Ale.

Comment: Gomathi, really I do not get your problem :-) I asked you before if you working with the android.widget.EditText and you answer was yes. Therefore my answer. Now you have this onKeyUp method again. Why you try to get the pressed key by this method and not by the one I told you ?

Answer (score 0):

Approach:Basic Idea is to get the unicode character. What it is and how to work with it, take a look on the links below. Following code shows three possibilities to get this unicode character from android.view.KeyEvent. Try what works for you.

```
android.view.KeyEvent event = ...you got the event

// first option
int unicode = event.getUnicodeChar();

// second option with meta-state
int unicode = event.getUnicodeChar(event.getMetaState());

// third option over the KeyCharacterMap
KeyCharacterMap map = event.getKeyCharacterMap();
int unicode = map.get(keyCode, event.getMetaState());

// once you have the unicode as integer you can do this to get the char
char unicodeChar = Character.toChars(unicode)[0];
```

UPDATE:
// for older versions of android

Check this out in order to get the android.view.KeyCharacterMap:

```
KeyCharacterMap map = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.BUILT_IN_KEYBOARD);
```

Or just try to get this map somehow over the static methods from the mentioned class.

Good Programming! :-)

Some interesting links:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html

Comment: Hi Alessandro i tried first and second option it's not working .I will try to third option i am using version 5.0 .It's not support this method getKeyCharacterMap().Give me any solution.

Comment: Hi Alessandro Thank you so much for your reply.But i have one problem getKeyCharacterMap() not supported.If i passed static unicode got value.Give me solution.How to get unicode otherway.

Comment: Hello Gomathi, your are welcome! Is it a physical keyboard or the virtualized keyboard?

Comment: Hi Alessandro Giusa i am using virtualized keyboard.

Comment: Hi Alessandro i got map value but i didn't get unicode.

Comment: Hello Homathi, please post your code in order to get more details to think about. Thanks!

Comment: KeyCharacterMap KeyMap=KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.BUILT_IN_KEYBOARD);
int unicode = KeyMap.get(event.getKeyCode(), event.getMetaState());
char unicodeChar = Character.toChars(unicode)[0];
Log.d("",""+unicodeChar)

Comment: Hi Alessandro Got KeyMap value but i didn't get unicode.Thanks

Comment: Okay thanks. And what is it what you get? What does the log print? Did you also play with some other KeyCharacterMap.*-Stuff what the class provides as static?

Comment: Hi Alessandro If we are past static value unicode we have to get easily.For Example int unicode ='\u00c7'; passed to Character.toChars got value.So i am trying to get dynamically get unicode.

Comment: If i am passed this unicode i got value "C" .Logcat show it C .If i am pressed any character keyboard got value only "C".Because i passed static unicode Alessandro.

Comment: Gomathi, I understand. My question was if you tried some other static literals different than KeyCharacterMap.BUILT_IN_KEYBOARD in order to get the unicode. ;-)

Comment: Hi Alessandro i got unicode from some other site.Just searched Character C unicode got value from there.Thanks

Comment: Hi Alessandro i won't try to someother different than KeyCharacterMap.BUILT_IN_KEYBOARD.Will try.

Comment: i tried KeyCharacterMap.load(event.getUnicodeChar()); keymap value got same.But i didn't get unicode Alessandro

Comment: Sorry but you do not understand what I mean. You have to get this unicode integer value somehow. Hence you do not get it over the options provided by me in my answer as you say, now you have to discover the KeyCharacterMap class at all to get further in you process. Once we know that at your specific environment this is not satisfying, we can think about more. :-)

Comment: Hi Alessandro It's possible get character key while typing android mobile used virtual keyboard ?

Comment: Please explain following: 1. What do you want to achieve? 2. Where are you typing stuff in? android.widget.EditText?

Comment: Hi Alessandro i am used in android.widget.EditText .If i am typing any word for example "S".I want to show it "S".But  i want to get character from keyboard not EditText.Thanks

Comment: See my answer below. Thanks:-)